# Login with SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot

I'm taking the first steps with SpringBoot ... I want to make a service Log in where you put a user and a password and if it is correct it returns the user's data.

At the moment, with what I can do the user's data according to, but I can solve what I want, I would appreciate it.

The problem that I have 2. I do not know how to send 2 parameters "username", "password" for a moment Send 1.

Repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import prueba.Usuario;

public interface UsuRepository extends CrudRepository<Usuario,String>{

}
```

usuarioClass:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usuario")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Usuario {

     @Id
     @Column(name="id")
     private int id;

     @Column(name="name")
     private String name;

     @Column(name="email")
     private String email;

     public Usuario() {
    }
     public Usuario(int id, String name, String email) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.email = email;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User[id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }
```

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value={"/usu"})
public class UsuController {

    @Autowired
    UsuService usuRepository;


     @RequestMapping("/")
        String home() {
            return "Servicio Usuario!";
     }


          @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, path = "/Login/{userName}" ,  produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Usuario Login(@PathVariable("userName") String userName) {
        Usuario tasks = usuRepository.getUsu(userName);
        return tasks; 
    }
```

Interface:

```
public interface UsuService { 
      public List<Usuario> getUsus() ;
      public Usuario getUsu(String name);
}
```

Service:

```
@Override
    public Usuario getUsu(String user) {
    Usuario usu;
    return usu = usuRepository.findOne(user);

    }
```

run:

```
http://localhost:8080/usu/Login/edu
```

Error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Jul 02 10:31:34 CEST 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Provided id of the wrong type for class prueba.Usuario. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.String; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for class prueba.Usuario. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.String
```

I already did a test returning all the users and it works.

At the moment I want to have my username, I return my data, and then I will do the Log in with password. Thanks.

I saw others tutorials The Login with SpringBoot, but this tutorials has "Security, encriptyng , etc " but I am new With this, I need service Login easy...

Comment: already , I updated

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing some concepts here. See you have this:

**1) Class Usuario with an id of type int:**

```
public class Usuario {

     @Id
     @Column(name="id")
     private int id;

     ...
}
```

**2) A request mapping receiving an user name of type String:**

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, path = "/Login/{userName}" ,  produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Usuario Login(@PathVariable("userName") String userName) { ...
```

**3) A repository configured with String as the id type of the Usuario entity:**

```
public interface UsuRepository extends CrudRepository<Usuario,String>
```

**Conclussion:**

When you do:

```
public Usuario getUsu(**String** user) {
    ...
    return usu = usuRepository.findOne(**user**);
}
```

You're asking the repository to find an Usuario entity with a **String** ID but Usuario has an **int** as an ID.

Therefore the error:

```
Provided id of the wrong type for class prueba.Usuario. **Expected**: class java.lang.Integer, **got** class java.lang.String; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for class prueba.Usuario. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.String
```

You need something like this:

```
public interface UsuRepository extends CrudRepository<Usuario,Integer> {

    Usuario getByName(String username);
}
```

Hope I helped. :-)